# Event handler inheritance

Tags: c#, events, derived-class, base-class

I have a parent class that is firing an event to derived classes. The problem is that the event handler is alway null.

```
Class Plugin()
{
    public delegate void BufferReadyHandler(string str);
    public event BufferReadyHandler OnBufferReady;
    public ClassPlugin(eGuiType _guyType)
    {
        GuiType = _guyType;
    }
    protected void Sp_DataReceived_Parent(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        strCommonBuffer += serial.ReadExisting();
        if (strCommonBuffer.Contains("\r\n"))
        {
            if (OnBufferReady != null) <<-------NULL
                OnBufferReady(strCommonBuffer);
            strCommonBuffer = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

then there are some derived classes that are linked to that event:

```
class ClassIO : ClassPlugin
{
    public ClassIO(eGuiType _guyType) : base(_guyType)
    {
        ...
        OnBufferReady += ClassIO_OnBufferReady;
    }

    private void ClassIO_OnBufferReady(string str)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

the problem is that the OnBufferReady event in the parent class is alway null and therefore never fired.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please use `EventHandler<T>`-based delegates for events. This is by convention in C#.

Comment: I cannot see the reason why the event could be not set. Please provide some examples how do you instantiate the classes.

Comment: @x But base. is not necessary since the derived class has not onbufferready event so automatically goes to the parent

Comment: How is Sp_DataReceived_Parent invoked?

Comment: If OnBufferReady is null then you know for a fact that the ClassIO(eGuiType) constructor did not execute.  That's probably because you also have a default constructor, we can't see it.  Delete it.  It is not the appropriate way to do this, a class should not listen for its own events.  Write a protected virtual method that raises the event, conventionally named OnYadayada() where Yadayada is the event name.  Override that method in a derived class, call base.OnYadayada().  Now you don't care at all if the event is subscribed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but have you thought about making the event static?

```
public delegate void BufferReadyHandler(string str);
public static event BufferReadyHandler OnBufferReady;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are having this problem, I suspect it has something to do with the code you have not shown us. However in this situation I would not have the child subscribe to the event at all, instead make a protected method that raises the event that the child can override.

Here is how I would implement the class.

```
public class BufferReadyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public BufferReadyEventArgs(string commonBuffer)
    {
        CommonBuffer = commonBuffer;
    }
    public string CommonBuffer {get; private set;}
}

Class Plugin()
{
    public event EventHandler<BufferReadyEventArgs> OnBufferReady;
    public ClassPlugin(eGuiType _guyType)
    {
        GuiType = _guyType;
    }
    protected void Sp_DataReceived_Parent(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        strCommonBuffer += serial.ReadExisting();
        if (strCommonBuffer.Contains("\r\n"))
        {
            RaiseOnBufferReady(strCommonBuffer);
            strCommonBuffer = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void RaiseOnBufferReady(string commonBuffer)
    {
        var temp = OnBufferReady;
        if(temp != null)
            temp(this, new BufferReadyEventArgs(commonBuffer));
    }
}

class ClassIO : ClassPlugin
{
    public ClassIO(eGuiType _guyType) : base(_guyType)
    {
        ...
    }

    protected override void RaiseOnBufferReady(string commonBuffer)
    {
        base.RaiseOnBufferReady(commonBuffer);

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The base class PluginClass is abstract does this change something?

Comment: @Luca no, does not change any of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example based on your code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ClassIO c = new ClassIO();
        c.DataReceived();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class ClassPlugin
{
    public delegate void BufferReadyHandler(string str);
    public event BufferReadyHandler OnBufferReady;

    public ClassPlugin()
    {
    }

    public void DataReceived()
    {       
        if (OnBufferReady != null) {
            OnBufferReady("Calling OnBufferReady");
        }
    }
}

public class ClassIO : ClassPlugin
{
    public ClassIO() : base()
    {
        OnBufferReady += ClassIO_OnBufferReady;
    }

    private void ClassIO_OnBufferReady(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside ClassIO_OnBufferReady");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Forgive my dumbness but ... what's different from my code?

Comment: @Luca nothing, which means your problem is in the code you did not show us.

Comment: I doubt this is the problem but two things, your code declared class Plugin but then inherited class ClassPlugin. And what raises the DataReceived event? You saw how I instantiated ClassIO and then manually called DataReceived on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would like to work with events in the first place for communication between parent and derived class.

If you need this communication, you would be better of with an (abstract) method in your base class that you implement in your derived classes.

If you need communication to all instances of derived types, you should look into composition instead of inheritance. Make some sort of manager instance that holds references to a list of instances of that base type and invokes a certain method on each of them in case of an 'event'.